# Operator does not exist: character varying = record in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to execute query in community edition version of postgres:

```
select COUNT(*) 
from cdar_cpms_owner.hshldgrp_wkly_actvty 
where wkly_actvty_cd  IN (('B','H') ,'N')
```

From that query, I get this error:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = record
>
> LINE 1: ..._owner.hshldgrp_wkly_actvty where wkly_actvty_cd  IN(('B','H...
>                                                                   ^
>   HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

While the same query is working fine with the EDB version of postgres.

Can anyone please suggest what changes are required in this query to make it work?

Comment: What is `('B','H')` supposed to be? That does not make any sense to me. Did you mean `('(''B'',''H'')', 'N')`?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
where wkly_actvty_cd IN ( ('B','H'),'N')
```

Your list has a nested list element: `('B','H')`. So Postgres ends up trying to compare a scalar value (`wkly_actvty_cd`) to a tuple, which raises the error that you are getting.

Did you actually mean?

```
where wkly_actvty_cd IN ('B', 'H', 'N')
```

Comment: No, I wanted to compare with nested list element: ('B','H') and 'N'. Strange thing here is  the query working fine with Enterprise Postgres with wkly_actvty_cd IN ( ('B','H'),'N'), but not in Community Edition Postgres.

Comment: @Saurabhwagh: please explain what is the logic you want for the comparison. You want `wkly_actvty_cd` whose value is `'B'`, `'H`', or '`N'`? Or is it something else (what)?

Comment: Sorry but even I am not sure this complete logic. I found this logic written in legacy code, I tried with this `where wkly_actvty_cd  IN('N')` it also gives me same count as `where wkly_actvty_cd IN ( ('B','H'),'N')`. so  I think `where wkly_actvty_cd  IN('N')` this logic will also works in query, Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Saurabhwagh: I can't tell you *what* the logic you want is. I can only tell you *how to* implement some logic, if you can describe it...